# XSLT/XPATH : process XHTML files to convert delimited text portions into new <SPAN> class

Tags: xslt, xpath

I got a bunch of files testX.xhtml that are edited in a browser using contenteditable=true. The purpose of the edit is to delimit portions of text with two identical characters like the underscore character in this xhtml file :

{xhtml source file} :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="text/css" xml:space="preserve"/>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
        <title>title XHTML</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <span class="ok">_blablabla blebleble_ bliblibli</span>
        <p class="ko">blablabla _blebleble bliblibli <em class="em">one em tag</em> blablabla blebleble._</p>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

The edited file is saved and then processed by the following xslt in order to have the tagged portion embedded in a new span class named my_span for further treatment :

{xslt file} :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
                version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                
    <xsl:output method="xhtml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" standalone="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>   
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="/">
    
         <xsl:for-each select="collection('?select=test*.xhtml')">
      
            <xsl:variable name="path_to_span">
                    <xsl:value-of select="iri-to-uri(replace(document-uri(current()), '.xhtml', '.span.xhtml'))"/>
            </xsl:variable>
        
    
            <xsl:result-document indent="yes" method="xhtml" href="{$path_to_span}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/> 
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
        
    </xsl:template>

    
    <xsl:template match="//text()">
            
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(.*?)_(.*?)_">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                <span class="my_span">
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                </span>
            
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
        
     </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

producing the following :

{produced xhtml file} :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <style xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="text/css" xml:space="preserve"></style>
      <title>title XHTML</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       
       <span class="ok"><span class="my_span">blablabla blebleble</span> bliblibli</span>
       
       <p class="ko">blablabla _blebleble bliblibli <em class="em">one em tag</em> blablabla blebleble._</p>
   
   </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, I figured out that some p tags contain em or i or similar tags that are not handled by my XSLT.

I would like to be able to produce this xhtml :

{expected xhtml file} :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <style xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="text/css" xml:space="preserve"></style>
      <title>title XHTML</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       
       <span class="ok"><span class="my_span">blablabla blebleble</span> bliblibli</span>
       
       <p class="ko">blablabla 
       
       <span class="my_span">blebleble bliblibli </span>
       
       <em class="em"><span class="my_span">one em tag</span></em>
       
       <span class="my_span">blablabla blebleble.</span>
        
       </p>
   
   </body>
</html>
```

I simplified the xhtml source file to one em tag not handled by my XSLT but there may be many combination of similar tag in one p tag.

In my expected xhtml file, I located the added span inside the em but swapping them would work too.

How to achieve this in XSLT ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: One approach to tackle such tasks is to use at least two steps, the first converts the delimiter character into an element node (e.g. `<del/>` or processing instruction, the second using grouping with e.g. `group-starting-with` and `group-ending-with` to wrap stuff into the `span` container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to convert the `_` character into a processing instruction `<?marker?>` in one transformation step, then in a second pair such `<?marker?>`s into `<?open?>`/`<?close?>` pairs to finally use a recursive function to group any such pairs based on `for-each-group group-starting-with="processing-instruction('open')` with a nested `for-each-group group-ending-with="processing-instruction('close')"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
    <xsl:param name="wrap-class" as="xs:string">my_class</xsl:param>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
      
    <xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="marked-content">
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="analyze"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="paired-content">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="$marked-content/node()" mode="pair-markers"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$paired-content/node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[processing-instruction('open')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(node())"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:mode name="analyze" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template mode="analyze" match="text()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., '_')" mode="mark"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template mode="mark" match="fn:*">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template mode="mark" match="fn:match">
      <xsl:processing-instruction name="marker"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:mode name="pair-markers" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template mode="pair-markers" match="processing-instruction('marker')">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer">
            <xsl:number/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$pos mod 2 = 1">
                <xsl:processing-instruction name="open"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:processing-instruction name="close"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:function name="mf:group">
        <xsl:param name="nodes" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$nodes" group-starting-with="processing-instruction('open')">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::processing-instruction('open')">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="tail(current-group())" group-ending-with="processing-instruction('close')">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                                <span class="{$wrap-class}">
                                    <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group()[position() ne last()])"/>
                                </span>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:function>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtDX

Comment: Thank you so much Martin. As I imagined, this is a complex XSLT, I will take some time to thoroughly understand it.

Comment: I spent a good amount time to understand your high skill XSLT. This was a great introduction to XSLT 3.0 for me. Many thanks again.